# What happens if an invalid address is prefetched?

Tags: c, caching, assembly, disassembly, prefetch

Simple MWE:

```
int* ptr = (int*)malloc(64 * sizeof(int));
_mm_prefetch((const char*)(ptr + 64), _MM_HINT_0);
```

1. Is this defined or undefined behavior?
2. Can this raise a signal and abort the program run?

I'm asking since I can see such prefetching in compiler generated code, where inside a loop prefetching is done without checking the address (stored in `rbx`):

```
400e73:       49 83 c5 40             add    r13,0x40
400e77:       62 f1 f9 08 28 03       vmovapd zmm0,ZMMWORD PTR [rbx]
400e7d:       4d 3b ec                cmp    r13,r12
400e80:       62 d1 f9 08 eb 4d ff    vporq  zmm1,zmm0,ZMMWORD PTR [r13-0x40]
400e87:       90                      nop
400e88:       62 d1 78 08 29 4d ff    vmovaps ZMMWORD PTR [r13-0x40],zmm1
400e8f:       72 03                   jb     400e94 <main+0x244>
400e91:       49 89 c5                mov    r13,rax
400e94:       62 f1 78 08 18 53 1d    vprefetch1 [rbx+0x740]
400e9b:       ff c1                   inc    ecx
400e9d:       62 f1 78 08 18 4b 02    vprefetch0 [rbx+0x80]
400ea4:       48 83 c3 40             add    rbx,0x40
400ea8:       81 f9 00 00 10 00       cmp    ecx,0x100000
400eae:       72 c3                   jb     400e73 <main+0x223>
```

Comment: Did you have a look at the documentation?

Comment: Intel Intrinsics Guide does not say anything about it. Nor Intel Intrinsics Refernce. Nor Intel Xeon Phi Instruction Set Reference (the disassembled code was compiled for KNC). As far as I know. I've found only this remark in What every programmer should know about memory: _Programs can use the _mm_prefetch intrinsic on any pointer in the program. Most processors (certainly all x86 and x86-64 processors) ignore errors resulting from invalid pointers which make the life of the programmer significantly easier._

Comment: Good points. Thank you for having a look before asking this question. Interesting that such an important detail remains undocumented!

Comment: Maybe one note: Xeon Phi Instruction Set Reference does not list the page fault (PF) exception for `VPREFETCHx`. For generic programming with intrinsics, one should thus probably find an answer by checking instruction references for all possible architectures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, the compiler doing it or you doing it are very different things in theory. Just because it looks equivalent doesn't make it so, the compiler is allowed to use any dirty hacks that work no matter whether they're expressible or defined in fully standard C.

Of course prefetching doesn't generate signals*, it would be nearly useless if it did. It can be very slow for some invalid pointers though, depending on whether they trigger a TLB miss. So the compiler can safely use it, but it shouldn't indiscriminately use it for everything ever.

Now using pointer arithmetic to create out of bounds pointers (except just past the end) is UB in theory, but when applied to a pointer it's the kind of UB that will mostly work anyway (with flat memory it's just an addition, the only way it could fail is if the compiler goes out of its way to detect it, and that means it would have to reason about dynamic sizes). Obviously the above case must be supported by compilers claiming to support SSE intrinsics otherwise you couldn't reasonably use prefetching, as demonstrated by this answer (and there's a bunch more extra guarantees they must make on top of the Standard).

* from the manual:

> The PREFETCHh instruction is merely a hint and does not affect program behavior.

Signal would affect program behavior, so they cannot be generated.

Comment: While creating out-of-bounds pointers is well-behaved on common architectures, it is likely that future compilers assume that if you compute a pointer, it is valid and the compiler can dereference it ahead of time / speculatively, thus leading to undefined behaviour if it is not valid.

Comment: @FUZxxl IA64 compilers already do that, but it's fine there. Still, it can't break like that *at least* in the case of using that pointer for prefetching otherwise it would just be broken.

Comment: UB? This is hardware, not a language standard.

Comment: It's a hack as well, `_mm_prefetch` is not a part of the C/C++ standards. I asked more about what CPU does, maybe the MWE in C was not  a good idea. Howerver, as you pointed out, even out of bounds pointers in C++ are UB according to the standard (except of a one-past-the-last special case).

Comment: Is there a performance hit to prefetching an invalid address?

Comment: @user541686 there can be a performance hit, since it results in a TLB miss (on x86, the TLB is not allowed to cache invalid translations) which ties up a load unit for a significant duration. How bad that is depends on the context. A loop that only prefetches invalid addresses and does nothing else gets quite slow (~23 cycles per prefetch on Haswell in my test), but in a context with a lot of surrounding arithmetic (and not many loads) that cost may be hidden. By the way it seems that prefetching a *super* invalid address (a non-canonical address on x64) is fast.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! Would be nice to add it to the answer in case people are interested in other consequences beside program logic.